# Android ScaleAnimation seems to ignore pivot

Tags: android, animation, pivot

My custom ScaleAnimation seems to ignore its pivot point. Here is my super-call:

```
super(1.0f, widthFactor, 1.0f, heightFactor, pivotX, pivotY);
```

When I set pivotX to 1.0f and pivotY to 0.0f the top-left corner is fixed although it should be the top-right corner that is fixed.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe try with view.getLeft() and view.getTop() where view is the view on which you're trying to apply the animation instead of 1.0f and 0.0f? I'm a bit of android newbie myself, but using these has worked for me.

Comment: Thank you! This way works and 1.0f would work when RELATIVE_TO_SELF is set.